# Prove $A$ is a linear continuous operator, if $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Assume $A$ is a map from real normed space $E$ to $F$ such that $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay \ \forall \ x, y \in E$ and $A$ is bounded on unit ball $B(0,1) \subset E$. Prove $A$ is a linear continuous operator.

**Could someone please help me with this?**

The only problem is I can't see how to prove 
$A(\alpha x) = \alpha Ax$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

For linearity, one can in effect assume that $E$ is one-dimensional. Fix $x\in E$
and define $\phi:\Bbb R\to F$ by $\phi(t)=A(tx)$. It suffices to prove $\phi$ is linear. It is additive, and bounded in a neighbourhood of zero. Then $\phi(t)=t\phi(1)$ for $t\in\Bbb Q$. Boundedness near zero implies (uniform)
continuity of $\phi$,
so taking limits gives $\phi(t)=t\phi(1)$ for $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Sr but how can you conclude that "ϕ(t)=tϕ(1)  for t∈Q"?

Comment: @NguyễnRèo additivity